# How do I correct [object%20Object] in URL path when using EmberJS transitionToRoute from Controller?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I'm attempting to setup an action in a template to transition users to another route based on a dynamically generated navbar, using a combination of json / and js that is executed client side. I've managed to configure my application so that I can generate regular paths that work, but I would like to use transitions to avoid additional page loads.

A gist with what is (hopefully) the necessary information is:

https://gist.github.com/rjfranco/5289201

JS:

```
App.Router.map ->
  @route 'index', {path: "/#{short_name}"}
  @route 'customList', {path: "/#{short_name}/custom-list/:list_name"}
  @route 'multiLevelList', {path: "/#{short_name}/multi-level-list/:list_name/:list_level"}

App.EventController = Em.ObjectController.extend
  goTo: (navbar_icon) ->
    @transitionToRoute navbar_icon.route, navbar_icon.context

# Sample passed navbar_icon
navbar_icon =
  img_src: '/somesource_or_another.jpg'
  display_name: 'My Link Name!'
  route: 'customList'
  context: {list_name: 'Exhibitors'}
```

template:

```
{{#each controller.navbarIcons}}
  <li><a {{action goTo this}}><img {{bindAttr src="image_src"}} width="36" height="36" />{{display_name}}</a></li>
{{/each}}
```

The expected page actually loads fine, but the url the application transitions to is not correct, and refreshing breaks the application.

I'm expecting a URL along the lines of: `/ruhaha/custom-list/Exhibitors`
and I end up with one like: `/ruhaha/custom-list/[object%20Object]`

**Slight update:**
I've found that I could abuse a couple of methods on the app to produce the results I want:

App.handleURL('/ruhaha/custom-list/Exhibitors')
App.Router.router.replaceURL('/ruhaha/custom-list/Exhibitors')

This will actually trigger the route, and replace the url effectively transitioning my application to the state I want without a page request. Although this works I'm pretty certain this is the wrong way to take care of this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up resolving this issue (with some help from nerdyworm on freenode) by specifying a serialize method in my route that just returned the param I was expecting:

```
App.CustomListRoute = Em.Route.extend
  serialize: (params) ->
    params
```